# Showing particular area from a texture by passing some points - OpenTK

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, opentk

Using below shader code, I can show an image as it is. Now I want to show the portions of image in a way that :

I have three GLcontrols.

First glcontrol should show the first portion of one by third part of image in a curved shape as shown in image. So I have to pass three points L1,L2,L3 and should show those connected area on it.

And  the second glcontrol should show the last portion of one by third part of image in a curved shape. For that I have to pass the points R1,R2,R3.

And the third glcontrol should show the remain center portion of image.

```
 public void CreateShaders()
    {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
                                varying vec2 vTexCoord;
                                void main() {
                                vTexCoord = (a_position.xy+1)/2 ;
                                gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1);
                                }");
        GL.CompileShader(vertShader);

        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"precision highp float;
        uniform sampler2D sTexture;
        varying vec2 vTexCoord; 
        uniform int sCurrentGLControl;
        uniform int L1;
        uniform int L2;
        uniform int L3;
        uniform int R1;
        uniform int R2;
        uniform int R3;
        void main ()
         {
        vec4 color;
        if(sCurrentGLControl==1) //first half
        {
         color = texture2D (sTexture, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y));
        }
        else if(sCurrentGLControl==2) //third half
        {
         color = texture2D (sTexture, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y));
        }
        else if(sCurrentGLControl==3) //second half
        {
          color = texture2D (sTexture, vec2(vTexCoord.x, vTexCoord.y));
        }          
        gl_FragColor =color;
 
         }"); GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the yellow dots are not relevant, and you are actually sampling from L1,L2,L3,R3,R2,R1 to create a double trapezoid shape, yes you will be able to map this to a curved surface or warped on a flat surface (going along the yellow dots would need more than 6 vertices). It's probably more difficult to write your shader to handle this, so instead pass in different uv coordinates to the shader from the rest of your program. So lift the GLControl related code out of shaders, and use it to determine draw calls with different buffered vertices (different vTexCoord).